# JVM crash in WindowAccessbridge

Tags: java, c++, dll, native

Found a below error in javaaccesbridge screen capturing.

This error occur randomly. 
Please let me know cause of this error? Please suggest me how to fix it?

1. ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

   Current thread (0x05d31800):  JavaThread "Thread-6" daemon
   [_thread_in_Java, id=16140, stack(0x04d60000,0x04db0000)]

   siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x08ed9e50

   Registers: EAX=0x08ed9e50, EBX=0x028502ff, ECX=0x04daf708,
   EDX=0x00000001 ESP=0x04daf624, EBP=0x04daf684, ESI=0x04daf710,
   EDI=0x34780498 EIP=0x0218b335, EFLAGS=0x00010206

   Top of Stack: (sp=0x04daf624) 0x04daf624:   05d31800 0218b877
   00000002 05d31800 0x04daf634:   05c59ec8 05d31800 04daf7d4 05d31800
   0x04daf644:   05c87b18 34780498 2ae9b7f8 04dafbc0 0x04daf654:
   02859fa5 04dafbf4 04daf7d4 05d31800 0x04daf664:   02404148 023b3ed8
   023b3f04 023b42cc 0x04daf674:   04dafc98 04daf7dc 0000000a 023b3ef8
   0x04daf684:   04daf6c8 0221d551 04daf7d4 01daf6f0 0x04daf694:
   04daf708 02881dc0 05c59ec8 05d31800

   Instructions: (pc=0x0218b335) 0x0218b315:   85 c0 7e 29 56 8d 9b 00
   00 00 00 8b 41 34 80 3c 0x0218b325:   02 00 74 10 8b 41 30 8d 34 90
   8b 06 85 c0 74 02 0x0218b335:   8b 00 89 06 8b 41 38 42 3b d0 7c df
   5e 8b 41 30 0x0218b345:   c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 55 8b ec
   8b 45

   Register to memory mapping:

   EAX=0x08ed9e50 is an unknown value EBX=StubRoutines::call_stub
   [0x028502ff, 0x028503b1[ (178 bytes)ECX=0x04daf708 is pointing into
   the stack for thread: 0x05d31800 EDX=0x00000001 is an unknown value
   ESP=0x04daf624 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x05d31800
   EBP=0x04daf684 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x05d31800
   ESI=0x04daf710 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x05d31800
   EDI=0x34780498 is an oop {method}

   - klass: {other class}

   Stack: [0x04d60000,0x04db0000],  sp=0x04daf624,  free space=317k
   Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code,
   C=native code) V  [jvm.dll+0xfb335] V  [jvm.dll+0x18d551] V 
   [jvm.dll+0xfb90d] V  [jvm.dll+0x96301] V  [jvm.dll+0x97dbc] C 
   [Automation.JavaBridge-32.dll+0xc21b] 
   JNIEnv_::CallObjectMethod+0x1b C 
   [Automation.JavaBridge-32.dll+0x4cea] 
   AccessBridgeJavaEntryPoints::getAccessibleContextInfo+0x5a C 
   [Automation.JavaBridge-32.dll+0xd1d9] 
   JavaAccessBridge::processPackage+0x299 C 
   [Automation.JavaBridge-32.dll+0xe40f] 
   JavaAccessBridge::receiveMemoryPackage+0x5f C 
   [Automation.JavaBridge-32.dll+0xca12]  AccessBridgeDialogProc+0xa2 C
   [USER32.dll+0x8e71]  CallNextHookEx+0xb1 C  [USER32.dll+0x1f46c] 
   EnableMenuItem+0x3ac C  [USER32.dll+0x1f2d7]  EnableMenuItem+0x217 C
   [USER32.dll+0x329f5]  DrawTextExA+0xf5 C  [USER32.dll+0x8e71] 
   CallNextHookEx+0xb1 C  [USER32.dll+0x90d1]  CallNextHookEx+0x311 C 
   [USER32.dll+0x932c]  CallNextHookEx+0x56c C  [USER32.dll+0x9529] 
   CallNextHookEx+0x769 C  [ntdll.dll+0x40596] 
   KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x36 C 
   [Automation.JavaBridge-32.dll+0xccdf] 
   JavaAccessBridge::javaRun+0x1af j 
   Automation.JavaAccessBridge.run()V+0 j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 v
   ~StubRoutines::call_stub V  [jvm.dll+0xfb88b] V  [jvm.dll+0x18d551]
   V  [jvm.dll+0xfba31] V  [jvm.dll+0xfba8b] V  [jvm.dll+0xb5e89] V 
   [jvm.dll+0x119b74] V  [jvm.dll+0x14217c] C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565] 
   endthreadex+0xa0 C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x17c04]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
   C  [ntdll.dll+0x5ab8f]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x8f C 
   [ntdll.dll+0x5ab5a]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x5a

   ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

   Java Threads: ( => current thread )
   =>0x05d31800 JavaThread "Thread-6" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=16140, stack(0x04d60000,0x04db0000)]   0x05d33400 JavaThread
   "EventQueueMonitor-ComponentEvtDispatch" daemon [_thread_blocked,
   id=15116, stack(0x02550000,0x025a0000)]   0x00498800 JavaThread
   "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=18240,
   stack(0x025e0000,0x02630000)]   0x05bb6800 JavaThread "TimerQueue"
   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14712, stack(0x05e50000,0x05ea0000)]
   0x05ba0800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=1228,
   stack(0x05dc0000,0x05e10000)]   0x0241cc00 JavaThread "AWT-Windows"
   daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1940, stack(0x056c0000,0x05710000)]
   0x0241c400 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=17868,
   stack(0x05630000,0x05680000)]   0x0241bc00 JavaThread "Java2D
   Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15196,
   stack(0x055a0000,0x055f0000)]   0x023ab800 JavaThread "Low Memory
   Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11740,
   stack(0x04f30000,0x04f80000)]   0x023aa400 JavaThread "C1
   CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11376,
   stack(0x04ea0000,0x04ef0000)]   0x023a9400 JavaThread "Attach
   Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16920,
   stack(0x04e10000,0x04e60000)]   0x023a7400 JavaThread "Signal
   Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5076,
   stack(0x04ca0000,0x04cf0000)]   0x0239cc00 JavaThread "Finalizer"
   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10284, stack(0x04c10000,0x04c60000)]
   0x0239b800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked,
   id=412, stack(0x04b00000,0x04b50000)]

   Other Threads:   0x0235ec00 VMThread [stack: 0x04a70000,0x04ac0000]
   [id=19372]   0x023c2400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x04fc0000,0x05010000]
   [id=9724]

   VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

   VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

   Heap  def new generation   total 14400K, used 7654K [0x24570000,
   0x25500000, 0x29ac0000)   eden space 12864K,  57% used [0x24570000,
   0x24caf7b0, 0x25200000)   from space 1536K,  15% used [0x25200000,
   0x2523a140, 0x25380000)   to   space 1536K,   0% used [0x25380000,
   0x25380000, 0x25500000)  tenured generation   total 31788K, used
   20658K [0x29ac0000, 0x2b9cb000, 0x34570000)    the space 31788K, 
   64% used [0x29ac0000, 0x2aeecaa0, 0x2aeecc00, 0x2b9cb000) 
   compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 2578K [0x34570000,
   0x35170000, 0x38570000)    the space 12288K,  20% used [0x34570000,
   0x347f4a48, 0x347f4c00, 0x35170000)
       ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x38570000, 0x38aa3000, 0x38aa3000, 0x38f70000)
       rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x38f70000, 0x3960e4f8, 0x3960e600, 0x39b70000)

   Code Cache  [0x02850000, 0x02a18000, 0x04850000)  total_blobs=1133
   nmethods=918 adapters=150 free_code_cache=31719552
   largest_free_block=320

   Dynamic libraries: 0x00400000 - 0x00425000  C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe 0x77190000 - 0x772ff000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 0x766c0000 - 0x76800000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL 0x74f90000 - 0x75067000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll 0x577a0000 - 0x57840000
       C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll 0x780c0000 - 0x78325000
       C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcGenral.DLL 0x75330000 - 0x753f3000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll 0x76e30000 - 0x76e71000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll 0x74980000 - 0x7499e000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll 0x76e80000 - 0x76ec5000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll 0x6ee30000 - 0x6ef1d000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\UxTheme.dll 0x76f60000 - 0x770b3000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll 0x75070000 - 0x7517f000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll 0x6ef80000 - 0x6efa3000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll 0x669e0000 - 0x669f3000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\samcli.dll 0x768a0000 - 0x769c9000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll 0x75180000 - 0x75217000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll 0x62830000 - 0x62847000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSACM32.dll 0x74790000 - 0x74798000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll 0x75400000 - 0x766bb000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll 0x6e710000 - 0x6e72b000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll 0x6ee10000 - 0x6ee2a000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll 0x6e5c0000 - 0x6e70b000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll 0x75220000 - 0x7529c000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll 0x6f200000 - 0x6f265000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV 0x6b7b0000 - 0x6b7c6000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll 0x769d0000 - 0x76a8a000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll 0x74970000 - 0x7497a000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll 0x76a90000 - 0x76c0d000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll 0x6ef50000 - 0x6ef73000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll 0x70440000 - 0x7044f000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll 0x6e2c0000 - 0x6e4f4000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll 0x6e740000 - 0x6e99c000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WININET.dll 0x74910000 - 0x74964000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll 0x752f0000 - 0x7532c000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll 0x6ef20000 - 0x6ef41000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll 0x70c90000 - 0x70d1b000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.DLL 0x752a0000 - 0x752c7000
       C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL 0x74c50000 - 0x74d62000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll 0x74830000 - 0x748aa000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SYSFER.DLL 0x6d340000 - 0x6d5ce000
       C:\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint
   Protection\14.0.1904.0000.105\Data\Definitions\IPSDefs\20170316.021\IPSEng32.dll 0x004d0000 - 0x00526000    C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll 0x02090000 - 0x02340000     C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll 0x00530000 - 0x00553000
       C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\splashscreen.dll 0x024e0000 -
   0x024ec000  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
   0x02740000 - 0x0275f000     C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll 0x02840000 - 0x0284f000    C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll 0x747a0000 - 0x747a9000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll 0x05010000 - 0x0515c000
       C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll 0x66b40000 -
   0x66d46000
       C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17415_none_a9ed7f470139b3c1\COMCTL32.dll
   0x05b20000 - 0x05b76000     C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll 0x05f30000 - 0x05f43000
       C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll 0x74d80000 -
   0x74dcf000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll 0x74de0000 - 0x74de7000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll 0x6f380000 - 0x6f3cb000
       C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll 0x04d10000 - 0x04d19000     C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll 0x70300000 - 0x70319000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll 0x702d0000 - 0x70300000
       C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll 0x70c70000 - 0x70c8e000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll 0x76ed0000 - 0x76f5d000
       C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll 0x02450000 - 0x02475000     C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\jpeg.dll 0x02480000 - 0x0249a000
       C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\instrument.dll 0x024b0000 -
   0x024b9000  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\management.dll
   0x0f330000 - 0x0f3a2000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Automation Anywhere
   Enterprise 10.3\Client\Java\Automation.JavaBridge-32.dll 0x02500000

   - 0x02506000    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\jawt.dll 0x05740000 - 0x05763000   C:\Program Files
     (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\dcpr.dll 0x74dd0000 - 0x74dd6000
     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL

   VM Arguments: java_command: D:\E
   Drive\SAS\SwingSet2\SwingSet2\SwingSet2.jar Launcher Type:
   SUN_STANDARD

   Environment Variables: PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
   Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;USERPROFILE.dnx\bin;C:\Program
   Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
   SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
   Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
   Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\ USERNAME=Mahen
   OS=Windows_NT PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 61
   Stepping 4, GenuineIntel

   ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

   OS: Windows 8 , 64 bit Build 9200

   CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 61
   stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1,
   sse4.2, popcnt, ht

   Memory: 4k page, physical 16478568k(8574852k free), swap
   18968936k(8387300k free)

   vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.45-b01) for windows-x86 JRE
   (1.6.0_45-b06), built on Mar 26 2013 13:40:03 by "java_re" with MS
   VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

   time: Fri Mar 17 19:18:57 2017 elapsed time: 261 seconds

Comment: So what do you need? You never asked a question.

Comment: By mistake entered. Update the question.

Comment: "JRE (1.6.0_45-b06)" - Perhaps you should first try and see what happens if you run your program on a version of Java that is still supported?

Comment: Is there any issue with "JRE (1.6.0_45-b06)" ?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in AccessBridgeDialogProc that affects 64-bit versions that persists through Java 8 but seems to be fixed in Java 9.